# How to solve Fatal exception and can not Resolve symbol 'R' in android?

Tags: android

[image]

I am working on my college final year project, as I do not have much knowledge about android developing I am encountering these two errors, when I add some files or images to drawable again and again, that to only in my main file only,  I tried all stackoverflow solutions( Rebuild clean project everything), can anyone tell me what I am missing here? And also I am facing problems in android manifest file, I have followed all the steps of developer.android.com and udacity but I think there is some problem with that too,  here is my manifest file:`

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pinalmeruliya.current.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.pinalmeruliya.current.Splash" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.pinalmeruliya.current.Splash" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:parentActivityName = "com.example.pinalmeruliya.current.MapsActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.pinalmeruliya.current.Splash" />
    </activity>


</application>
```

`

please help me with this.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this your whole manifest file?

Comment: R not resolve means not problem in `manifest`. it means problem is `res` dir problem layout names, image names, strings,colors or id of Views used in layouts or Views

Comment: @p.patel You should read the description of a tag before you commit it.